# Change Cordova plugin language on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7

I'm building an app with Cordova 3.5 on iOS 7, and it's not for native English user. So I want change the plugin language, like "Use", "Retake" in camera, or "Done" on keyboard. I can't find any setting or option in Cordova doc, how to do that?

Comment: @Franz Sorry but no luck here, I think you can find something like i18nSheet in iOS project, but I don't have knowledge about native iOS.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is provided in Cordova. Instead, you can do it in your Xcode project settings. In your project, select Info → **Localization native development region** and change it to your desired language.

[image]

Comment: Not work for me. I'm tried that and clean-rebuild again, but it's still English :(

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml in the codrdova project, under the  tag add this:

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion">
            <string>Your_Language</string>
 </edit-config>
```

It will create an entry in the .plist file

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>German</string>
```

of the ios project generated during the **ionic cordova build ios** process